# Fill matrix with loop

Tags: r, simulation, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix `n` by `k` with `k` mvn covariates using a loop.
Quite simple but not working so far...  Here is my code:

```
n=1000
k=5
p=100
mu=0
sigma=1
x=matrix(data=NA, nrow=n, ncol=k)


for (i in 1:k){
        x [[i]]= mvrnorm(n,mu,sigma)
       }
```

What's missing?

Comment: Matrices don't work like that. Try using `x[,i]` not `x[[i]]`. An easier way to do it with no loop is `x<-matrix(data=rnorm(n*k,mu,sigma), nrow=n, ncol=k)`

Answer (score 14):

I see several things here:

1. You may want to set the random seed for replicability (`set.seed(20430)`).  This means that every time you run the code, you will get exactly the same set of pseudorandom variates.
2. Next, your data will just be independent variates; they won't actually have any multivariate structure (although that may be what you want).  In general, if you want to generate *multivariate* data, you should use [?mvrnorm](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/mvrnorm.html), from the [MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html) package.  (For more info, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of).)
3. As a minor point, if you want *standard* normal data, you don't need to specify `mu = 0` and `sigma = 1`, as those are the default values for `rnorm()`.
4. You don't need a loop to fill a matrix in R, just generate as many values as you like and add them directly using the `data=` argument in the `matrix()` function.  If you really were committed to using a loop, you should probably use a double loop, so that you are looping over the columns, and within each loop, looping over the rows.  (Note that this is a very inefficient way to code in R--although I do things like that all the time ;-).
5. Lastly, I can't tell what `p` is supposed to be doing in your code.

Here is a basic way to do what you seem to be going for:

```
set.seed(20430)
n   = 1000
k   = 5
dat = rnorm(n*k)
x   = matrix(data=dat, nrow=n, ncol=k)
```

If you really wanted to use loops you could do it like this:

```
mu    = 0
sigma = 1
x     = matrix(data=NA, nrow=n, ncol=k)

for(j in 1:k){
   for(i in 1:n){
        x[i,j] = rnorm(1, mu, sigma)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

define the matrix first

```
E<-matrix(data=0, nrow=10, ncol=10);
```

run two loops to iterate i for rows and j for columns, mine is a exchangeable correlation structure

```
for (i in 1:10)
{ 
  for (j in 1:10) 
  {
    if (i==j) {E[i,j]=1}
    else {E[i,j]=0.6}
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A=c(2,3,4,5);# In your case row terms
B=c(3,4,5,6);# In your case column terms
x=matrix(,nrow = length(A), ncol = length(B));
for (i in 1:length(A)){
     for (j in 1:length(B)){
          x[i,j]<-(A[i]*B[j])# do the similarity function, simi(A[i],B[j])       
     }
}
x # matrix is filled
```

I was thinking in my problem perspective.