# How do I populate a 10x10 matrix in R with values 1-100 using two for loops?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

How do I populate a 10X10 empty matrix called mat.horiz, with values 1 to 100 by row (i.e. filling in values across columns, in descending rows), using two for() loops?

New to loops and am barely grasping the structure of them. Any help and explanation would be much appreciated:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill matrix with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685911/fill-matrix-with-loop)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `for` loops, you can try the code below

```
out <- matrix(NA,10,10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    out[i,j] <- j + (i-1)*10
  }
}
```

or

```
out <- matrix(NA,10,10)
k <- 0
for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    k <- k + 1
    out[i,j] <- k
  }
}
```

---

A simpler way is using

```
out <- matrix(1:100,10,10,byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: @catesb Yes, I see. I added another option using counter

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding! Yeah, I am aware of the much simpler strategy of populating the matrix within matrix() but I was required to do it with a loop. The loop within the loop was confusing me. I hadn't thought of just using a mathematical function in the {statement} either. I was attempting to populate it by earlier defining a counter of counter <- i+1 and using that within the {statement}